# Why does WordPress loop never end?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running WordPress on the PHP7/XAMPP server and I am trying to make a simple "theme" Here is the code for the theme.

**code-listing 1: header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Blog Post</title>

    </head>
    <body>
```

**code-listing 2: index.php**

```
<?php 
    get_header();
?>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <!-- Blog Posts -->
                <?php
                    if(have_posts()){
                        while(have_posts){
                            the_post();
                            if(the_post_thumbnail()){
                                the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
                            }
                            the_content();
                        }
                    }
                ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

<?php 
    get_footer();
?>
```

**code-listing 3: footer.php**

```
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

**code-listing 4: functions.php**

```
<?php

    add_theme_support("post-thumbnails");
```

Whenever I load a page I get this PHP error:

```
`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\W`WW\wordpress473\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 4786
```

the line where the error occurs can be different but the error always occurs on the same script.
When loading a page the loop keeps loading the same post over and over again until PHP stops the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about wordpress, but this line over here:

```
if(have_posts()){
   while(have_posts){
      the_post();
         if(the_post_thumbnail()){
            the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
         }
      the_content();
   }
}
```

You are checking the result of "have_posts()" and the in the loop you use "have_posts". If it's the function that returns an Iterable then you should fix that typo and loop over "have_posts()" in the while loop.

This is what I found in the docs, looks like I was rigth:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Your loop code
endwhile;  
else :
_e( 'Sorry, no posts were found.', 'textdomain' );
```

endif;